# Routing to a module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Disclaimer: This is my first time programming in angular and it's quite possible that this is a misconception and therefore my question is invalid

---

I've started to write an app that is supposed to get several complex features. So I put a single feature in a single module so that I can just load the whole module as a simple import into my app and just have it in HTML.

Simplified folder structure

```
app.module.ts
app.component.ts
app.component.html
feature/feature.module.ts
feature/componentA/componentA.component.cs
...
```

in the `FeatureModule`  I export my main component which contains all the sub-components.

Then in `AppModule` I load the other module like that

```
import { FeatureModule } from './feature/feature.module';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ .. ],
  imports: [
    .. ,
    FeatureModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Then I can add the feature component in my html. That's it.

But now I want to add routing and  I need to specify a specific component, not a module.

This leads to my question: How should I route this? Or: How should I structure my complex feature to *hide* all the internals from the outside. I just want to expose a single "piece" that I can insert into my app. Plug and Play, if you will

Answer (score 1):

Look at lazy loading and the Route's loadChildren property.

Your route would look like:

```
const routes: Routes = [

      {
        path: 'items',
        loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)
      }
    ];
```

And then the lazy-loaded module would have its own routing to specify what component is shown when the module is routed to. Can be just a single route, if you have only one 'feature' component in the  module.

The documentation is at https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 1):

You can use lazy loading of routes to basically just point a route to your `FeatureModule`, and then let your `FeatureModule` have it's own route. This way everything inside your feature expect it's base level module is hidden from your base router which I believe is what you want ?

For instance:

In app-routing.module.ts

```js
...

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'feature', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./feature/feature.module.ts').then(m => m.FeatureModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Add your router module to you app.module.ts

```js
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you can add a route to your components inside `FeatureModule`

```js
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'componenta',
    component: ComponentA
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  ...
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

[Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)